# How to make Spring Security MD5 password before calling LDAP

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-security, md5

I am working on a project using Spring and Spring Security with LDAP.  I had my project working great with LDAP before we MD5 the user passwords.  Now that we MD5 the users passwords I am trying to find a way in the Spring XML to tell Springs to MD5 the password before checking LDAP.

Below is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/friends/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/articles/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=sampleusers" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=xxxwf,dc=org" />
        <beans:property name="userDn" value="cn=admin,dc=xxxwf,dc=org" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="sabrina123" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>uid={0},ou=sampleusers</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
        </beans:constructor-arg>

    </beans:bean>
    <ldap-server url="ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=xxxwf,dc=org" />

    <beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />


    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <beans:property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <beans:property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Passwords should be sent in the clear over a secure connection, they should not be pre-encoded with digest or pre-encoded in any way - pre-encoded passwords prevent the directory server from performing password quality checks. The directory server encrypts or hashes the clear-text password and compares the password to the one that is encrypted/hashed in the target entry and returns success or failure in the bind response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider>
        <security:password-compare>
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:password-compare>
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" 
      class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

I have not tryed it with LDAP. But it defently works for "normal" (not LDAP) authentication-provider.

Answer (score 0):

Terry's answer is correct, if you are using bind authentication, the Spr Sec LDAP client is attempting to bind to LDAP using the provided username and plaintext password (incidentally, this is why SLDAP is always recommended if you are using bind authentication).

If you are using password compare authentication, the password that you are using to compare must be hashed or encoded to exactly match the password stored in the LDAP repository.

Since it looks like you're using bind authentication, you should be fine as things currently stand.

These concepts are pretty well covered in the [LDAP section of the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html).